# Getting SolrException "solrconfig editing is not enabled due to disable.configEdit " in DSE 6.8.34

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to edit the solrconfig.xml file in a Linux environment where DSE is installed. However, I have been unable to locate the file and have also attempted to edit it via the Config API. When attempting to do so, I receive the following message: "solrconfig editing is not enabled due to disable.configEdit." Additionally, I cannot find the .sh file for Solr.

I have tried the following command:

```
POST http://localhost:8983/solr/keyspace.mytable/config
```

But received this response:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 403,
        "QTime": 27
    },
    "error": {
        "metadata": [
            "error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
            "root-error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
        ],
        "msg": " solrconfig editing is not enabled due to disable.configEdit",
        "code": 403
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use dsetool get_core_config to get the solrconfig.xml file:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/dsetool/dsetoolGet_core_config.html

You can also get it via cqlsh:

```
DESCRIBE PENDING SEARCH INDEX CONFIG on keyspace.tablename;
```

Comment: Thank you! I am able to upload new solrconfig using DSEtool

"dsetool write_resource keyspace_name.table_name name=res_filename file=path_to_file_to_upload"

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/dsetool/dsetoolWrite_resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Access to perform certain administrative operations on the Solr UI including indexing and reloading cores have been disabled for security reasons in DataStax Enterprise ([DSP-13530](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/releaseNotes/RNdse.html#RNdse510__510searchResIss)).

We recommend using `dsetool` to manage Search indexes. For example, to retrieve a copy of the Solr configuration for a core:

```
$ dsetool get_core_config ks.table
```

Manually edit the downloaded `solrconfig.xml` file then upload it and trigger a reindex at the same time using the `reload_core` command. For example:

```
$ dsetool reload_core ks.table \
    solrconfig=/path/to/solrconfig.xml \
    schema=/path/to/schema.xml \
    distributed=true \
    reindex=true \
    deleteAll=false
```

For details, see [Managing search indexes with dsetool commands](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/dsetool/dsetoolSearchIndex.html). Cheers!